# PDF to open in a iFrame instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I am displaying the number of records using HRef along with Title, all my records are coming from the WordPress connector which are types of PDFs and WebPages. I want to have a my PDF file open in iFrame instead of downloading it. Currently when I am clicking on Href, It is asked me to start downloading.I need this using ASP.NET. I don't have even any control from WordPress connector. It is simple third party.

Simple thing is I want to open a PDF file in iFrame instead of downloading. I want this using JQuery, so when user clicks it will be loaded into the iFrame.

Harshal

Comment: which browser are you using

Comment: Just saying, some versions of adobe have been known to cause trouble with some browsers (read Internet Explorer). I wouldn't recommend using pdf iframes.

Comment: I am using latest Chrome, FF

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, I need to open them in iFrame to read a through there only instead of downloading it.